# ¿Como debo hacer la transformación de coordenadas en MatLab?

Tags: matlab

De cartesianas a polares, de cartesianas a cilíndricas, de cartesianas a esféricas y de esféricas a cartesianas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la siguiente **imagen** tienes todas las **transformaciones** que necesitas:

[image: Transformación de coordenadas MATLAB]

Si necesitas más información puedes visitar: [Introducción al MATLAB](https://www.modeladoeningenieria.edu.ar/images/MatSup/Curso_de_Introduccion_a_MATLAB.pdf). Allí encontrarás una amplia explicación sobre como utilizar **MATLAB**.

Espero te sea de utilidad. Un Saludo.

Comment: Gracias! Es de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @MiguelArias De nada. Un saludo